# Как в делфи выровнять текст по ширине

Tags: delphi, выравнивание

Есть текст, записанный в `RichEdit` в несколько строк. Как мне весь текст выровнять по ширине по нажатию клавиши?

Answer (score 1):

Как то так:

```
const
  TO_ADVANCEDTYPOGRAPHY         = $0001;
  TO_SIMPLELINEBREAK            = $0002;
  EM_SETTYPOGRAPHYOPTIONS       = $04CA;
  PFA_JUSTIFY                   = $0004;
  // Rich Edit 2.0: Paragraphs are justified. This value is included for compatibility with TOM interfaces; rich edit controls earlier than Rich Edit 3.0 display the text aligned with the left margin.
  PFA_FULL_INTERWORD            = $0005;
  // Paragraphs are justified by expanding the blanks alone.
procedure TForm1.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  lParagraph: TParaFormat2;
begin
  ZeroMemory(@lParagraph, SizeOf(TParaFormat2));
  lParagraph.cbSize := SizeOf(TParaFormat2);
  lParagraph.dwMask := PFM_ALIGNMENT;
  lParagraph.wAlignment := PFA_JUSTIFY;
  SendMessage(redt1.Handle, EM_SETTYPOGRAPHYOPTIONS, TO_ADVANCEDTYPOGRAPHY, TO_ADVANCEDTYPOGRAPHY);
  SendMessage(redt1.Handle, EM_SETPARAFORMAT, 0, Integer(@lParagraph));
end;
```

Пример взят [отсюда](http://forum.vingrad.ru/topic-153506.html)